# mysql - select email from xyz where email="%gmail.com"

Tags: php, mysql, wildcard

Is there a way I can select from the database the entries with certain data? I got a lot of email addresses in the database but I want to select only from one domain. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure - just use the [LIKE](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp) operator.

```
SELECT email FROM Persons
WHERE email LIKE '%gmail.com'
```

Comment: No problem. Feel free to mark [this answer as accepted and correct](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), but I advice you to take a look at the answer from ajreal as well. When you have a huge database and looking for performance, his solution is faster than a wildcard search. For small databases/not many visitors (or just "the quickest way" to develop/extract the data from the database), a wildcard search is good enough.

Answer (score 2):

You are not advisable to do a wildcard search.
This is because mysql not able to use index to fasten the select query.
Especially you mention you have lots of email in the database.

Alternatively, you can use an additional field, as `hostname` to store just the hostname only.
And of course build an index to it.

If you need to search for email with `gmail.com`,
then you can do straight string comparison

```
SELECT email FROM Persons
WHERE hostname='gmail.com';
```

As the straight string comparison is the good mate to mysql index, your query will be optimized.

Comment: As I commented on my answer, this answer indeed **is** a better solution than a wildcard search when looking for speed/performance.

Answer (score 1):

As [ajreal points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14517985/592139), MySQL can't use indexes to optimise a LIKE query in the general case. However in the specific case of a *trailing* wildcard where the only `%` is at the very end of the pattern (effectively a "starts with" query), the optimiser can do a good job of speeding up the query using an index.

Therefore, if you were to add an additional indexed column storing the email address in reverse, you could efficiently query for

```
SELECT email FROM xyz WHERE reverse_email LIKE 'moc.liamg@%`
```

to find all gmail addresses, or `LIKE 'ku.%` for all addresses under uk domains, etc.  You can have the database keep this column up to date for you using triggers, so it doesn't affect your existing update code

```
CREATE TRIGGER emailinsert BEFORE INSERT ON xyz
FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.reverse_email = REVERSE(NEW.email);

CREATE TRIGGER emailupdate BEFORE UPDATE ON xyz
FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.reverse_email = REVERSE(NEW.email);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `LIKE MYSQL CLAUSE`

```
SELECT * FROM email_table WHERE email LIKE "%gmail.com"
```

Comment: ohh my bad i didn't realized that i added =... +1 for you.